# Why doesn't Slack format my <!date> message?

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to format a date in a Slack message via the Web API. I'm using Botkit and thus my fields are being parsed with Mustache, however logs show that the correct formatting is coming out afterwards (therefore I don't think Mustache is the issue here).

The message as shown in Botkit debug logs is `"... on <!date^1511407982054^{date_long_pretty} at {time}|Wednesday at 10am> ..."`. Other `<formatting>` in the message works just fine both before and after this occurrence.

I'm sure I'm at fault, but can't figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Slack rendering:

[image: screenshot in Slack]

Some things I've tried:

- sending a message that *only* contains the date format string
- I've been using `new Date().getTime()` to generate the value. Tried using `new Date().getTime() * 1000` in case there was a difference there (moment.js does a * 1000 when you ask for a unix epoch number - maybe units are different).

Comment: If you're posting the message via RTM and not `chat.postMessage`, it's possible the `<!date>` syntax is not part of the very narrow formatting options allowed when posting via RTM.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looking closer at the library (I'm using Botkit), it uses RTM to receive messages, but unless you explicitly configure send_via_rtm, it uses the Web API for sending messages. So I'm actually using the web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use `Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)` to generate the Unix timestamp